# VBA: регулярное выражение для выделения определённых частей из строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, excel, vba

Подскажите пожалуйста как для Excel VBA должно выглядеть регулярное выражение, чтобы выделить из текста вида

```
12345.12345TEXT12345
```

т.е. (число точка число текст число (опционально))

число до текста и сам текст

например:

```
строка: 4320.17AB32

найдено: 4320.17 and AB
```

или

```
строка: 50.1702ZZA

найдено: 50.1702 and ZZA
```

Написал:

```
Dim regEx As New RegExp
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = "[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*$"
End With

Set matches = regEx.Execute(text)
```

Но похоже в регулярках вообще ничего не понимаю :( ибо находит только полную строку

Comment: Используйте захватывающие группы: `\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([A-Za-z]*)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, огромное спасибо! Надо все таки наконец то эту магию выучить :)))

Answer (score 0):

Используйте захватывающие группы:

```js
\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([A-Za-z]*)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Jbpuku/1). **Подробности**:

- `\b` - граница слова
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - захватывающая подмаска №1 (`.Submatches(0)`): одна и более цифр, а затем необязательная последовательность: точка + одна и более цифр
- `([A-Za-z]*)` - захватывающая подмаска №2 (`.Submatches(1)`): ноль и более букв ASCII.

Пример кода на VBA:

```
Dim regEx As regExp, Matches As Object, m As Object
Dim str As String

Dim coll As Collection

str = "текст: 4320.17AB32"
Set regEx = New regExp
regEx.Pattern = "\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([A-Za-z]*)"

Set Matches = regEx.Execute(str)

If Matches.count > 0 Then
 For Each m In Matches
  Debug.Print "Найдено: " & m.SubMatches(0) & " и " & m.SubMatches(1)
 Next
End If
```

Результат: `Найдено: 4320.17 и AB`